# Avoid user to open web app in multiple tabs or window

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, web, internet-explorer-8

I have multipage application and I need to check if user was alredy open an app in other browser tab or in other browser window (IE8) and avoid this (logout user in opened new window/tab)

I use JSP, JavaScript and jQuery

If its real - not to use sessionStorage

EDITED
I also use iframes and IE8 modal dialogs.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to use a technology like SignalR that keeps a connection open. Then you'd need to ping the connections to see if that user is connected and close out their existing connection. If that implementation is too daunting, you can add a timer loop to your app/page that calls the logins table (or whatever storage device for these events) and if there are new logins, calls its own logout procedure.

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to maintain a map (in memory or in db based on user count) in your application scope which stores `username vs session-id`. On every login, you lookup in this map if already a `session` exist for that `username`. If exist, invalidate existing session, else store the new `session-id` in map. [not tested]

Answer (score 0):

you can pass the the user session id or random generated id to global/window variable, ie;

```
window.state = 'SomeLoginIdString';
```

keep the state in some other variable where you client pages can easily access, preferably a datastore on client.

```
var loginAccessCurrentState = 'SomeLoginIdString';
```

When use open/switch pages compare both, if it false you can redirect to a 404 page.

```
loginAccessCurrentState  === window.state
```

The idea is you only pass the state during login session, if user open a new tab, the state is undefined by default.

Comment: Will it work if i use iframes (same origin) with ie modal dialogs? Window variable will be undefined in them, but window.parent.state maybe not...

Answer (score 0):

For single page applications the following way could be an easy solution:

1. Create a random ID on the entry page, store it in the session and in the GUI
2. On each Ajax call add the random ID to the request as additional HTTP header
3. if the ID does not match between given header and session, the application was opened in another tab/window and this call is coming from the "old" tab
4. the resulting answer of the server must then lead the GUI to lock / close itself in the affected tab